# Remove post content from buddypress activity

Tags: buddypress

I'm trying to remove the post content from the buddypress activity stream and would like to replace the content/body with a custom field that I've added in.

Any ideas where I should be looking?  I've been looking around for a while and cant seem to figure it out.

I am using WordPress 3.4.1 & Buddypress 1.5.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should state which versions of WP and BP you're using.

This should change the content part of what is recorded. 
You can put it in your theme's functions.php

```
add_filter( 'bp_blogs_activity_new_post_content', 'record_post_activity_content', 1, 3 );
function record_post_activity_content($activity_content, $post, $post_permalink ){
    if( $post->post_type == 'post' ) {
        $activity_content = 'your custom field';
    }
        return $activity_content;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, my bad forgot about that!
WordPress 3.4.1 & Buddypress 1.5.6

I'll try what you're recommending and get back to you, thanks!